# Is it possible to use the spread operator (three dots) except specific keys?

Tags: javascript

Is the spread operator have the exception feature? like:

```
  originalObject = {
    key1: '',
    key2: '',
    key3: ''
  }

  const clonedOriginalObject = {
    ...object,
    // except key2
  }
```

So what I'm excepting is the `clonedObject` contains only key1 and key2

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can use [Destructuring_assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to omit `key2` and get the `rest` :

```js
originalObject = {
  key1: "",
  key2: "",
  key3: ""
};

const { key2, ...clonedOriginalObject } = originalObject;

console.log(clonedOriginalObject);
```

Comment: Note that this also declares and assigns to a const variable called `key2` in the current scope.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can create a helper function `omit` that takes an array of keys to omit, and then an object. It will return a shallow copy of the object with the specified keys omitted. Such a function might look like this:

```js
const omit = (keys, obj) => Object.entries(obj)
    .filter(([key]) => ! keys.includes(key))
    .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => ({ ...acc, [key]: value }), {});
    
const originalObject = {
    key1: 'val1',
    key2: 'val2',
    key3: 'val3',
}

console.log(
  omit(['key2'], originalObject)
);
```

Function `omit` will first convert the key-value pairs to arrays of keys and values with `Object.entries`. (`[key, value]`). This allows us to iterate the own keys of the source object while maintaining access to the corresponding values. Then we filter these pairs by absence of the key in the given `keys` to omit. When that is done, a new object is constructed from the pairs with the `reduce` call.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, it's good but my question is more about the spread operator

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that, and Taki already answered your question perfectly. I just thought it would be a good idea to show you (in addition) an alternative that does not 'pollute' the scope, as noted by Paulpro in the comments.

Comment: This also works for keys that are not valid identifiers, EG. `omit( ['some-data'], { 'some-data': 5, 'foo': 'bar' } );`, You can't do that with destructuring assignment.